# Is there a standard way for implementing a tab navigation with individual navigation histories using react router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-navigation

My goal is to implement a tab navigation similar to Instagram's bottom navigation bar where each tab has its own navigation stack (history). This way, when a user clicks/ scrolls through screens in one tab, switches to another tab, and subsequently switches back to the initial one, the (nested) screen in the current tab and scroll position was remembered, so that the user resumes where he/she left off.

Is there an elegant way to implement this for react web using react router? Or is there another more suitable routing library for react?

Comment: React router is the go to library for react, I am not sure about the scrolling position. You should create a demo project to this it yourself

Comment: I already did. The problem is, whether it would be possible to have separate navigation stacks/histories for each tab.